# Restricting user to enter only double or int values in C# razor view

Tags: c#, razor

I am new to C# and trying to put some validation around textbox.

I am trying to create a smart textbox that will restrict user to enter any alphabet.

I want these inputs to be acceptable by textbox and should not allow user to enter any other character

valid

34.54
23
2.3433

Invalid 
abcf 
(user will press key but there should be nothing on screen i.e. rejected)

34.33.443.22

Here is my textbox code in C# View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreditLimitSaveData.CreditLimit, new { @maxlength = "20", @size = "20" })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict user's input for only containing numbers, periods and whitespaces, use this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// if you intend to use vanilla JS rather than jQuery, replace $("#text").keypress with document.getElementById("text").onkeypress
$("#text").keypress(function (evt) {
     // keyCode note:
     // 46 = delete
     // 49-57 = numbers 0-9
     // 32 = whitespace
     // 190 = period
     var code = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
     // if you want to allow left-right arrow, include checks for keyCode 37 & 39
     if (code != 46 && (code < 48 || code > 57) && code != 32 && code != 190) {
         return false;
     }
     else {
         return true;
     }
});
</script>

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreditLimitSaveData.CreditLimit, new { @maxlength = "20", @size = "20", @id = "text" }
```

The id htmlAttribute element is required to enforce validation rule.

CMIIW.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute `type` as `number` to allow `int` values.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreditLimitSaveData.CreditLimit, new { @maxlength = "20", @size = "20", @type="number" }
```

`maxlength` will not work with `input type="number"` so you will need some `javascript` to restrict this.